# How to enable rewrite module for all subfolders?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to enable rewriting for all websites on my server.

Instead of having to add for each website

```
<Directory /var/www/mywebsite1>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mywebsite2>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

...
```

Can I just write something like

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

to specify I want rewrite enable on all subfolders ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following question answered here on ServerFault will answer your question:

[Apache: Using same Directory directive for multiple virtual hosts](https://serverfault.com/questions/37321/apache-using-same-directory-directive-for-multiple-virtual-hosts)

Short version is, yes, you can generally place a Directory directive outside of your VirtualHosts containers so that it will be applicable to all VirtualHosts.

Comment: ok I see, so <Directory /var/www/*> is correct ? Or I actually don't need the * in the end ? I've actually tried both but it doesn't work. I'm missing something.. I've .htaccess file in the website directory and mod_rewrite is on

Comment: You have `RewriteEngine On`? Crank up the `RewriteLogLevel` to 3 to see what is happening.

Comment: If you want the `<Directory>` directive to match a regular expression, per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory, you need to use the ~ before the regex so that Apache knows how to interpret the directive (such as `<Directory ~ abc$>`.  But by default, "Directives enclosed in a <Directory> section apply to the named filesystem directory and all subdirectories of that directory", so you should not need a regex to apply to all subdirectories of /var/www (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#file-and-web).